# elasticsearch_dsl search by geo location distance and get results and distance

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have an index the holds location data for stores.

When using python's `elasticsearch_dsl` I'd like to find the nearest stores for a given location, sorted by distance. Since `ES` already calculates the distance, is it possible to get it as a part of the search result?

Can it be achieved using `elasticsearch_dsl` in a single query? Or do I have to do post processing on the location lat,lon and calculate the distances manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [sort by distance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#geo-sorting) and you'd get the computed distance in the resulting hits.

For instance:

```
s = Search().sort(
    {
        "_geo_distance" : {
            "location" : {"lat": 40, "lon": -70},
            "order" : "asc",
            "unit" : "km",
            "distance_type" : "arc"
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: That solution uses `elasticsearch_dsl`

Comment: Yes, it uses `elasticsearch_dsl`, but that is what the question asked for :)

Btw, updated link for the above:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#geo-sorting

If you want to use it with straight up ElasticSearch in Python, you need to add the above as the `sort` parameter